# Frame Buffer data format explanation

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

With a frame buffer like this

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufferObject);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject);
glGenTextures(1, &frameBufferTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RGB_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture, 0);
```

Does reading a pixel give you an unsigned int for each component such that

```
unsigned int* data=new unsigned int[width*height*3];
glReadPixels(0,0,width,height,GL_RGB_INTEGER,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,data);
```

Would data[0] be just the red component, or would it be the red, green, and blue component?

Comment: While `GL_RED_INTEGER`, `GL_RG_INTEGER` and `GL_RGBA_INTEGER` are color-renderable., `GL_RGB_INTEGER` may not be. See [Texture and Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Texture_and_Renderbuffer)

Comment: `GL_RGB_INTEGER` is not a packed format, so `data[0]` will be a single component and not the color packed into it. What confuses me is, that while you can use the `_INTEGER` suffix in `glTexImage2D` as `format` argument, the reference doesn't list it at `glReadPixels` (see [here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) and [here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Ahh okay thanks, and yes you are correct, thanks for catching my oversight